# Making generic classes Rails-y

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple class I want to include in my Rails app, but I want to still be able to access all the Rails niceness, e.g use the gems, helpers, routes etc etc as normal.

How can I do this?  Is it the right thing to do?

Comment: So you want to use this class, in your rails app ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't quite specify what the class is for. If it's a model, put it in the models folder. Don't forget that a model doesn't have to be backed by a database. If you have a class that represents something and has business logic, it's a model.

```
# models/report.rb
class Report
  def self.attendance_for(course)
     Enrollment.find :all, :include => [:sections], :conditions => ["sections.course_id = ?", course.id])
  end
  ....

end
```

The lib folder is also appropriate, but depending on how you name the file *and* the class definition, you may still need to require it from environment.rb or elsewhere.

Another approach is to use a plugin or a gem to distribute your code.

Answer (score 0):

you put it in the `lib` directory